# How to initialize logger log4j again for each class during runtime

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have never worked with logging before and I want to initialize the logger for each class again in the middle of the application. We are using `log4j` and On `each` class, we have

```
public class MyClass {
    
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);

    public void method(){
        logger.info("This is info");
    }
```

So what I want is to reinitialize this `logger` object at a certain point at runtime in my application. So far I have noticed that this `logger` object is initialized on `application startup` but I want to execute this

```
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

line while my application is running and user performs a certain action.

## **Objective:**

My real objective  is to store these log files on disk. But I want to store the log files on different folders depending on user actions. So we have two `siteIDs` in our application and therefore, we have made 2 folders on disk where we expect log files to be stored. So, when the site is selected these `logger` objects on `each class` needs to be reinitialized. Any suggestions how can I achieve this? Following is my log.properties file:

```
logger.pattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}.%M - %msg%n
logger.base.dir=../logs
logger.archive.dir=/archive
logger.archived.file.pattern=_%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.%i
logger.file.ext=.log
logger.file.size=10 mb
logger.archived.size.cap=100 mb
logger.file.retention.days=7
logger.debug.file.retention.days=1
logger.level=TRACE
```

Then we have a class named `LoggerConfig`

```
public class LoggerConfig {

private static LoggerConfig loggerConfig = null;

private Properties prop = new Properties();

private String pattern;
private String baseDir;
private String archiveDir;
private String archivedFilePattern;
private String fileExt;
private String fileSize;
private String archivedSizeCap;
private Integer fileRetentionDays;
private Integer debugFileRetentionDays;
private Level loggerLevel;

private LoggerConfig() {

    loadProperties();
}

public static LoggerConfig getInstance() {
    if (loggerConfig == null) {
        loggerConfig = new LoggerConfig();
    }
    return loggerConfig;
}

private void loadProperties() {
    try {
        InputStream input = LoggerConfig.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("logger.properties");
        prop.load(input);
        this.pattern = prop.getProperty("logger.pattern");
        this.baseDir = prop.getProperty("logger.base.dir");
        this.archiveDir = prop.getProperty("logger.archive.dir");
        this.archivedFilePattern = prop.getProperty("logger.archived.file.pattern");
        this.fileExt = prop.getProperty("logger.file.ext");
        this.fileSize = prop.getProperty("logger.file.size");
        this.archivedSizeCap = prop.getProperty("logger.archived.size.cap");
        this.fileRetentionDays = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("logger.file.retention.days"));
        this.debugFileRetentionDays = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("logger.debug.file.retention.days"));
        this.loggerLevel = Level.toLevel(prop.getProperty("logger.level"));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception occourred while loading the configration file " + ex);
    }
}

/**
 * Getters and setters
 */
```

And Finally another Logger file:

```
public class ApplicationLogger {

    private static LoggerConfig config = LoggerConfig.getInstance();

    private static Map<String, Logger> loggers = new HashMap<String, Logger>();

    public static Logger getLogger(String orgID, Class<?> className) {
        init(orgID, className);
        return loggers.get(orgID);
    }

    private static void init(String orgID, Class<?> className) {
        if (!loggers.containsKey(orgID)) {
            LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
            Logger logger = loggerContext.getLogger(orgID + className);
            logger.setAdditive(Boolean.FALSE);
            logger.setLevel(config.getLoggerLevel());

            logger.addAppender(getFileAppender(loggerContext, Level.TRACE, orgID));
            logger.addAppender(getFileAppender(loggerContext, Level.DEBUG, orgID));
            logger.addAppender(getFileAppender(loggerContext, Level.INFO, orgID));
            logger.addAppender(getFileAppender(loggerContext, Level.WARN, orgID));
            logger.addAppender(getFileAppender(loggerContext, Level.ERROR, orgID));
            
            loggers.put(orgID, logger);
        }
    }

    private static FileAppender<ILoggingEvent> getFileAppender(LoggerContext loggerContext, Level level, String orgID) {

        PatternLayoutEncoder encoder = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
        encoder.setContext(loggerContext);
        encoder.setPattern(config.getPattern());
        encoder.setImmediateFlush(Boolean.TRUE);
        encoder.start();

        LevelFilter filter = new LevelFilter();
        filter.setContext(loggerContext);
        filter.setLevel(level);
        filter.setOnMismatch(FilterReply.DENY);
        filter.start();

        RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent> fileAppender = new RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent>();

        SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy<ILoggingEvent> rollingPolicy = new SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy<ILoggingEvent>();
        rollingPolicy.setContext(loggerContext);
        rollingPolicy.setFileNamePattern(config.getBaseDir() + config.getArchiveDir() + File.separator + orgID
                + File.separator + level.toString() + config.getArchivedFilePattern() + config.getFileExt());
        rollingPolicy.setMaxFileSize(FileSize.valueOf(config.getFileSize()));
        rollingPolicy.setMaxHistory(
                Level.DEBUG.equals(level) ? config.getDebugFileRetentionDays() : config.getFileRetentionDays());
        rollingPolicy.setTotalSizeCap(FileSize.valueOf(config.getArchivedSizeCap()));
        rollingPolicy.setParent(fileAppender);
        rollingPolicy.start();
        fileAppender.setContext(loggerContext);
        fileAppender.setAppend(true);
        fileAppender.setEncoder(encoder);
        fileAppender.addFilter(filter);
        fileAppender.setFile(
                config.getBaseDir() + File.separator + orgID + File.separator + level.toString() + config.getFileExt());
        fileAppender.setRollingPolicy(rollingPolicy);
        fileAppender.start();

        return fileAppender;
    }
    
}
```

Please note orgID is the siteID which is changed by user and on changing it, I want to reinitialize all `logger` objects

Comment: You tagged your question `log4j`, but your code is based on Logback. Which logging framework do you want to use?

Comment: It seems that in config file, we have used `logback` logger but in classes we are using `log4j`. Is it wrong?

Comment: I can change to logback in classes as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard solution to you problem in Log4j2 is to use a single logger, the [`ThreadContext`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html) and a [`RoutingAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender). This requires almost no programmatic configuration:

1. At the beginning of your request processing your need to fill in a value for the `siteId` `ThreadContext` key:

   ```
   ThreadContext.put("siteId", "site1");
   ```
2. In your `log4j2.xml` file you need to configure a routing appender that chooses the real appender based on the value of `siteId`:

   ```xml
   <Configuration>
     <Appenders>
       <RollingFile name="ROLLING-site1" fileName="..." filePattern="...">
         ...
       </RollingFile>
       <RollingFile name="ROLLING-site2" fileName="..." filePattern="...">
         ...
       </RollingFile>
       <Routing name="ROUTING">
         <Routes pattern="$${ctx:siteId}">
           <Route key="site1" appenderRef="ROLLING-site1" />
           <Route key="site2" appenderRef="ROLLING-site2" />
         </Routes>
       </Routing>
     </Appenders>
     <Loggers>
       <Root level="DEBUG">
         <AppenderRef ref="ROUTING" />
       </Root>
     </Loggers>
   </Configuration>
   ```
3. Your classes can use a static logger obtained from `LogManager.getLogger` and do not need to be aware of the logic behind the choice of the appender.

A similar configuration can probably be obtained in Logback using filters, but my knowledge of Logback is quite limited.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer sir. Really appreciated.